# Compatibility Xamarin and FTDI Library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, ftdi

I want to program an app that can Read Data from a FTDI device that is connected via the USB port on an android device. I tried working with xamarin in visual studio 22 in c#.

So I am able to add the library (FTDI D2XX) into my project and also to use all the functions, but as soon as i want to emulate it, i get this error:

`System.NotSupportedException Message = Could not activate JNI Handle 0x7fffa3677900 (key_handle 0x8a201d9) of Java type 'crc6496017b555982539e/MainActivity' as managed type '(Myproject).MainActivity'`

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1at7A.png)

Its not a problem with the emulator or the program because when i remove all commands from the FTDI library only, it works fine.
Seems like a compatibility problem to me...

On startup of the app i see a warning:
`@(Content) build action is not supported (Path to my Project)\ftd2xx.dll`

Is there a way around? I choose VS and NET because i dont want to program the app in java. If anyone knows a solution please help! An alternative to this would be welcome as well

Tried to update the NET library, tried using the source code of the library, tried using a NuGet reference - all leading to the same error

Comment: we have no idea which library you are using

Comment: Seems similar to: [FTDI D2XX Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64922303/295004). Note Android CANNOT use Windows drivers so as the comment mentions you may need to create your own Xamarin bindings to Android compatible FTDI drivers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: @Jason I am using the FTDI D2XX driver library. and for CS i tried to implement it´s NET version